# What forms to submit to change the class from IR6 (through marriage) to another (divorced)?

Tags: marriage, divorce

I entered the states in 2002, got married in 2004 and obtained my conditional green card that way. After about 2 years I received my permanent card which is valid for 10 years. Now that I'm renewing the card within 6 months of expiration, do I need to change the admission class from IR6 to something else, or just leave it be as it is on the application?

Answer (score 1):

No. Your class of admission won't change. The code reflects how you got permanent residency, and a later divorce doesn't change that.